# What's the difference between Docker Compose vs. Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, development-environment, boot2docker

I have been reading up and learning about [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/), and am trying to correctly choose the Django setup to use. So far there is either:

[Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) or [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

I understand that *Dockerfiles* are used in *Docker Compose*, but I am not sure if it is good practice to put everything in one large Dockerfile with multiple `FROM` commands for the different images?

I want to use several different images that include:

```
uwsgi
nginx
postgres
redis
rabbitmq
celery with cron
```

Please advise on what are best practices in setting up this type of environment using *Docker*.

If it helps, I am on a Mac, so using [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker).

Some issues I've had:

1. Docker Compose is not compatible with Python3
2. I want to containerize my project, so if one large Dockerfile
   is not ideal, then I feel I'd need to break it up using Docker Compose
3. I am OK to make the project Py2 & Py3 compatible, so am leaning towards django-compose

Comment: The matter would be better phrased as “Should I run my app as a single or multiple containers?” It seems it depends and that matters of scaling and separation of concerns (one container per service) should be taken into account. These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534939/should-i-use-separate-docker-containers-for-my-web-app/30535869#30535869 and https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-advantage-of-having-multiple-Docker-containers-on-a-server-as-opposed-to-just-running-the-one-application-on-the-server?srid=ttRm

Comment: The official Docker ["Getting Started" docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/).

Comment: Install docker-compose by running ''' apt install python3 pip3 && pip3 uninstall docker-compose && pip3 install docker-compose, and there is no common issue on installing this way

Comment: I'd just like to note that this is a mega helpful question for one that is apparently "off topic".

Comment: [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66516826/4575793) might be related in a wider sense/interesting too. There I found out that it is "migrating [from Python] to Go".

Comment: [what is the difference between docker and docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966552/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-and-docker-compose)

Answer (score 338, accepted):

The answer is neither.

Docker Compose (herein referred to as compose) will use the Dockerfile if you add the build command to your project's `docker-compose.yml`.

Your Docker workflow should be to build a suitable `Dockerfile` for each image you wish to create, then use compose to assemble the images using the `build` command.

You can specify the path to your individual Dockerfiles using `build /path/to/dockerfiles/blah` where `/path/to/dockerfiles/blah` is where blah's `Dockerfile` lives.

Comment: do you use `docker-compose` in production or only dev?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @booyaa Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Dockerfile specify config for image, and docker-compose.yml assemble images together.. One thing I want to point out is that, If `docker-compose.yml` only use public image (pulling image from the internet/docker hub), then one don't need a Dockerfile to run command `docker-compose up`.

Comment: one gotcha I think is worth highlighting, especially in response to the question "is compose for production or dev?" (answer IMO: depends on use-case, but usually dev). `docker-compose` is what you want to use for managing multiple containers on a single VM. If you need to manage and network containers across multiple VMs, you want something like kubernetes or docker swarm. Check out some [common use-cases of docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#common-use-cases) on the docker website

Answer (score 784):

## Dockerfile

[image]

A Dockerfile is a simple text file that contains the commands a user could call to assemble an image.

Example,  **Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER john doe 

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip wget
RUN pip install Flask

ADD hello.py /home/hello.py

WORKDIR /home
```

---

## Docker Compose

[image]

**Docker Compose**

- is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications.
- define the services that make up your app in `docker-compose.yml` so they can be run together in an isolated environment.
- get an app running in one command by just running  `docker-compose up`

Example, **docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    - logvolume01:/var/log
    links:
    - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      logvolume01: {}
```

Comment: @sg the answer is that the question is ill-formed based on lack of understanding of Docker vs Docker Compose.  Succinctly explaining how the two interact is probably the best answer I can think of.

Comment: I see this kind of docs missing in most recently released tools/solutions/frameworks on the web. I guess it is hard to see why someone needs it in case you already know/invented the solution yourself.

Comment: What's missing from this answer is more info about compose. Does the compose script call the dockerfile? How does it know what to compose? The example shows `image: redis` but is that from dockerhub? local directory? etc... this makes it confusing for a newb like me to understand what's really going on

Comment: This response insists on the multi-container purpose of docker compose but there are probably many other scenarios you want to use docker compose even with only one container such as specifying the port you want your container run on (not possible in dockerfile afaik).

Comment: @omidrezabagheri your edit moved the declaration of the `logvolume01` inside the **redis** service - resulting in an invalid config.

If you are not familar with volume declarations outside of service definitions, take a look at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference
You may want to rollback that edit.

Comment: does docker-compose internally creates dynamic 'docker pull' & 'docker run' etc to run  a service?

Comment: You wrote "multi-container Docker applications", but your example does not user any multiple containers?

Answer (score 243):

docker-compose exists to keep you having to write a ton of commands you would have to with docker-cli.

docker-compose also makes it easy to startup multiple containers at the same time and automatically connect them together with some form of networking.

The purpose of docker-compose is to function as docker cli but to issue multiple commands much more quickly.

To make use of docker-compose, you need to encode the commands you were running before into a `docker-compose.yml` file.

You are not just going to copy paste them into the yaml file, there is a special syntax.

Once created, you have to feed it to the docker-compose cli and it will be up to the cli to parse the file and create all the different containers with the correct configuration we specify.

So you will have separate containers, let's say, one is `redis-server` and the second one is `node-app`, and you want that created using the `Dockerfile` in your current directory.

Additionally, after making that container, you would map some port from the container to the local machine to access everything running inside of it.

So for your `docker-compose.yml` file, you would want to start the first line like so:

```yaml
version: '3'
```

That tells Docker the version of `docker-compose` you want to use. After that, you have to add:

```yaml
version: '3'
services: 
  redis-server: 
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    build: .
```

Please notice the indentation, very important. Also, notice for one service I am grabbing an image, but for another service I am telling `docker-compose` to look inside the current directory to build the image that will be used for the second container.

Then you want to specify all the different ports that you want open on this container.

```yaml
version: '3'
services: 
  redis-server: 
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      -
```

Please notice the dash, a dash in a yaml file is how we specify an array. In this example, I am mapping `8081` on my local machine to `8081` on the container like so:

```yaml
version: '3'
services: 
  redis-server: 
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

So the first port is your local machine, and the other is the port on the container, you could also distinguish between the two to avoid confusion like so:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4001:8081"
```

By developing your `docker-compose.yml` file like this, it will create these containers on essentially the same network and they will have free access to communicate with each other any way they please and exchange as much information as they want.

When the two containers are created using `docker-compose`, we do not need any port declarations.

Now in my example, we need to do some code configuration in the Nodejs app that looks something like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: 'redis-server'
});
```

I use this example above to make you aware that there may be some specific configuration you would have to do in addition to the `docker-compose.yml` file that may be specific to your project.

Now, if you ever find yourself working with a Nodejs app and redis, you want to ensure you are aware of the default port Nodejs uses, so I will add this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: 'redis-server',
  port: 6379
});
```

So Docker is going to see that the Node app is looking for `redis-server` and redirect that connection over to this running container.

The whole time, the `Dockerfile` only contains this:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY /package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

So, whereas before you would have to run `docker run myimage` to create an instance of all the containers or services inside the file, you can instead run `docker-compose up` and you don't have to specify an image because Docker will look in the current working directory and look for a `docker-compose.yml` file inside.

Before `docker-compose.yml`, we had to deal with two separate commands of `docker build .` and `docker run myimage`, but in the `docker-compose` world, if you want to rebuild your images, you write `docker-compose up --build`. That tells Docker to start up the containers again but rebuild it to get the latest changes.

So `docker-compose` makes it easier for working with multiple containers. The next time you need to start this group of containers in the background, you can do `docker-compose up -d`; and to stop them, you can do `docker-compose down`.

Comment: @Chris It's almost as if there is 3 years worth of knowledge between this and the accepted answer.

Comment: I wonder if any good reason for me to use `docker-compose up` if just one service in my situation? Another word, compare with `docker run xxx`, any benefit if I use `docker-compose up`?

Comment: @atline see Pansoul's response to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45549372/3366962 on the benefits of using `docker-compose` for single containers

Comment: If you connect the local machine and the container via the `4001` port, how come you can connect redis via `6379`? Or is it that inside the node app, you are already in the container, and you're calling the redis server from within the container?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg you "Or" part is correct (and `6379` is the default port of Redis).

Comment: The examples for docker-compose.yml helped me answer some of the questions I had about docker-compose. The accepted answer is not useful, especially for people who are new to docker.

Comment: Oh Mahn, you should deserve the accepted answer.. crystal clear explanation. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 130):

Docker compose file is a way for you to declaratively orchestrate the startup of multiple containers, rather than run each Dockerfile separately with a bash script, which would be much slower to write and harder to debug.

Answer (score 65):

Dockerfile and Docker Compose are two different concepts in Dockerland. When we talk about Docker, the first things that come to mind are orchestration, OS level virtualization, images,  containers, etc.. I will try to explain each as follows:

**Image:**
An image is an immutable, shareable file that is stored in a Docker-trusted registry. A Docker image is built up from a series of read-only layers. Each layer represents an instruction that is being given in the image’s Dockerfile. An image holds all the required binaries to run.

[image]

**Container:**
An instance of an image is called a *container*. A container is just an executable image binary that is to be run by the host OS. A running image is a container.

[image]

**Dockerfile:**
A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all of the commands / build instructions, a user could call on the command line to assemble an image. This will be saved as a `Dockerfile`. (Note the lowercase 'f'.)

[image]

**Docker-Compose:**
Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services (containers). Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration. 
The Compose file would be saved as `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 57):

"better" is relative. It all depends on what your needs are. Docker compose is for orchestrating multiple containers. If these images already exist in the docker registry, then it's better to list them in the compose file. If these images or some other images have to be built from files on your computer, then you can describe the processes of building those images in a Dockerfile.

> I understand that Dockerfiles are used in Docker Compose, but I am not sure if it is good practice to put everything in one large Dockerfile with multiple FROM commands for the different images?

Using multiple FROM in a single dockerfile is not a very good idea because there is a proposal to remove the feature. [13026](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13026)

If for instance, you want to dockerize an application which uses a database and have the application files on your computer, you can use a compose file together with a dockerfile as follows

### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  volumes:
    - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
    - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
  ports:
    - "3307:3306"
app:
  build:
    context: ./path/to/Dockerfile
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ./:/app
  working_dir: /app
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
  mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
  && pecl install imagick \
  && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
  && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Answer (score 54):

In my workflow, I add a Dockerfile for each part of my system and configure it that each part could run individually. Then I add a docker-compose.yml to bring them together and link them.

Biggest advantage (in my opinion): when [linking the containers](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/links), you can define a name and ping your containers with this name. Therefore your database might be accessible with the name `db` and no longer by its IP.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on accessing the db by the name?

Comment: On which part? In docker-compose it is trivial, because it is the normal way when defining your services to give it a name and have it accessible without needing to configure it. In our CI I am creating a network, create the container in this network and give them a name. Then you have them also accessible by their name inside the containers (not from the host)

Comment: In composer I mean. So I link the images in composer, and in my App config instead of IP, I targer the MySQL by whatever name I gave it in composer file?

Comment: That's correct. You don't even have to specify a link. They are linked by default if the network is not differently specified. [In this example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-3-define-services-in-a-compose-file) the service "web" can ping the host "redis" by its name "redis"

Answer (score 21):

Imagine you are the manager of a software company and you just bought a brand new server. Just the hardware.

Think of `Dockerfile` as a set of instructions you would tell your system adminstrator *what to install* on this brand new server. For example:

- We need a Debian linux
- add an apache web server
- we need postgresql as well
- install midnight commander
- when all done, copy all *.php, *.jpg, etc. files of our project into the webroot of the webserver (`/var/www`)

By contrast, think of `docker-compose.yml` as a set of instructions you would tell your system administrator *how the server can interact* with the rest of the world. For example,

- it has access to a shared folder from another computer,
- it's port 80 is the same as the port 8000 of the host computer,
- and so on.

(This is not a precise explanation but good enough to start with.)

Answer (score 10):

Dockerfiles are to build an image for example from a bare bone Ubuntu, you can add `mysql` called `mySQL` on one image and `mywordpress` on a second image called `mywordpress`.

Compose YAML files are to take these images and run them cohesively.
For example, if you have in your `docker-compose.yml` file a service called `db`:

```yaml
services:
   db:
     image: mySQL  --- image that you built.
```

and a service called wordpress such as:

```yaml
wordpress: 
    image: mywordpress
```

then inside the mywordpress container you can use `db` to connect to your mySQL container.  This magic is possible because your docker host create a network bridge (network overlay).

Answer (score 4):

In Microservices world (having a common shared codebase), each Microservice would have a `Dockerfile` whereas at the root level (generally outside of all Microservices and where your parent POM resides)  you would define a `docker-compose.yml` to group all Microservices into a full-blown app.

In your case "Docker Compose" is preferred over "Dockerfile".  Think "App" Think "Compose".

Answer (score 4):

Dockerfile is a file that contains text commands to assemble an image.

Docker compose is used to run a multi-container environment.

In your specific scenario, if you have multiple services for each technology you mentioned (service 1 using reddis, service 2 using rabbit mq etc), then you can have a Dockerfile for each of the services and a common docker-compose.yml to run all the "Dockerfile" as containers.

If you want them all in a single service, docker-compose will be a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

When I first started learning Docker, the following example is what helped me understand it.

Suppose you have a `web-app + database` config which is a pretty common setup.

1. The `web-app` part is usually built with a Dockerfile. Because you will need some framework (like Python/Django, or NodeJS, or DotNet, etc) that actually runs your code, installs dependencies etc. So the `framework + web-app` lives in one container, tightly coupled, together, otherwise it won't work. That's the `Dockerfile's` job.
2. However the `database` part usually lives in a separate container, because the database is decoupled from the app. It runs on its own, it does not need NodeJS or anything, it is backed-up/restored separately from your `web-app`, the database server can be upgraded/downgraded separately etc... That is why you usually create that container separately. You take a database-engine public image (like Postgres, or SQL Server, MySQL, Mongo etc), open some ports, mount some volumes to persist the data, etc. etc.

And in the end you connect the two parts together using `docker-compose`, which, sort of, gives you a container with two "subcontainers" in it.

Comment: The phrase 'subcontainer' might be misleading to unexperienced people. In reality, it is two containers that are managed together.