# What is the difference between docker and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker` and `docker-compose` seem to be interacting with the same dockerFile, what is the difference between the two tools?

Answer (score 370, accepted):

The `docker` cli is used when managing individual containers on a docker engine. It is the client command line to access the docker daemon api.

The `docker-compose` cli can be used to manage a multi-container application. It also moves many of the options you would enter on the `docker run` cli into the `docker-compose.yml` file for easier reuse. It works as a front end "script" on top of the same docker api used by `docker`, so you can do everything `docker-compose` does with `docker` commands and a lot of shell scripting. See [this documentation on docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) for more details.

---

**Update for Swarm Mode**

Since this answer was posted, docker has added a second use of docker-compose.yml files. Starting with the [version 3 yml format](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/) and docker 1.13, you can use the yml with docker-compose and also to define a stack in docker's swarm mode. To do the latter you need to use `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml $stack_name` instead of `docker-compose up` and then manage the stack with `docker` commands instead of `docker-compose` commands. The mapping is a one for one between the two uses:

- Compose Project -> Swarm Stack: A group of services for a specific purpose
- Compose Service -> Swarm Service: One image and it's configuration, possibly scaled up.
- Compose Container -> Swarm Task: A single container in a service

For more details on swarm mode, see [docker's swarm mode documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/).

Comment: Do `docker run` and `docker compose up` (cli command with docker compose plugin v2) create similar default networks, assuming there is one service/container?

Comment: Docker is calling the same backend engine APIs from `docker compose up` and other docker commands. But it won't be a single `docker run` command since it is also creating networks and volumes, the equivalent of `docker network create` and perhaps `docker network connect` depending on the use case.

Comment: Thanks. So although one can run the same Dockerfile using either commands, the commands do not do the same thing; `docker compose up` is computationally heavier, all else being equal, right?

Answer (score 132):

**`docker`** manages single containers

**`docker-compose`** manages multiple container applications

Usage of *docker-compose* requires 3 steps:

1. Define the app environment with a **Dockerfile**
2. Define the app services in **docker-compose.yml**
3. Run **`docker-compose up`** to start and run app

[image: docker-compose up]

Below is a **docker-compose.yml** example taken from the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/):

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    - logvolume01:/var/log
    links:
    - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
```

Comment: For clarity's sake, the line  `build: .` in the `web` section points to the location of the Dockerfile created in step 1.

Comment: So how many containers will be created with the yml above? Do they share something, like FS?

Answer (score 6):

A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all the commands/Instruction a user could call on the command line to assemble an image.

Docker Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services. Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration. By default, docker-compose expects the name of the Compose file as `docker-compose.yml` or `docker-compose.yaml`. If the compose file has a different name we can specify it with -f flag.

[Check here for more details](https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/intermediate/workshop/DockerCompose/Difference_between_dockerfile_and_docker_compose.html)

Answer (score 4):

docker or more specifically docker engine is used when we want to handle only one container whereas the docker-compose is used when we have multiple containers to handle. We would need multiple containers when we have more than one service to be taken care of, like we have an application that has a client server model. We need a container for the server model and one more container for the client model. Docker compose usually requires each container to have its own dockerfile and then a yml file that incorporates all the containers.