# Docker-compose: replace "build"-based service with pre-built image in production?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Let's say we have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres"
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
  web:
    build: web
    depends_on: [ db ]
    ports:
     - "80:80"
```

The first service, `db`, just runs a container with the official postgres image from Docker Hub.

The second service, `web`, first builds a new image based on the `Dockerfile` in a folder also called `web`, then runs a container with that image.

While developing, we now can (repeatedly) make changes to whatever is in the `web` folder, then run `docker-compose up --build` to run our app locally.

Let's say we now want to deploy to production. My understanding is that `docker-compose.yml` can now be used to "define a stack in Docker's swarm mode" (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37966689) answer, for instance). However, for the `build` step of the `web` service, Docker's [compose file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) states that

> This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a (version 3) Compose file. The docker stack command accepts only pre-built images.

It probably wouldn't be a great idea to build the image on the production machine anyways, as this would leave build artifacts (source code) behind; this should happen on a build server.

My question is, is there a recommended way to modify `docker-compose.yml` en route to production to swap out `build: web` with `image: <id>` somehow?

Nothing on [Use Compose in production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/) on that. Is there something wrong with my approach in general?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`docker-compose.yml` should only contain canonical service definitions.

Anything that's specific to the build environment (e.g. dev vs prod) should be declared in a separate file `docker-compose.override.yml`. Each build environment can have its own version of that file.

The `build: web` declaration doesn't belong into `docker-compose.yml`, as it's only supposed to run locally (and possibly on a build server), not in production.

Therefore, in the example above, this is what `docker-compose.yml` should look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres"
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
  web:
    depends_on: [ db ]
    ports:
     - "80:80"
```

And this would be the default `docker-compose.override.yml` for local development:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: web
```

Running `docker-compose up --build -d` will now build the latest code changes and launch our app locally.

There could also be another version `docker-compose.override.build.yml`, targeting a build/CI server:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: web
    image: mydockeruser/web
```

Running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.build.yml push` will build the latest code changes and push the image to its registry/repository.

Finally, there could be another version `docker-compose.override.prod.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: mydockeruser/web
```

Deploying to production (just to a single Docker host, not a cluster) can now be as simple as copying over only `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.prod.yml` and running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.prod.yml up -d`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it (i.e. the way I do it :P) is to have different docker-compose files; for example, `docker-compose.dev.yml` and `docker-compose.prod.yml`. You can then push your production-ready image to a repository, say [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/), and reference that image in `docker-compose.prod.yml`'s `web` service. All the while you can use the dev docker-compose file (the one with the `build` option) for local development.

Also, in case you've thought about this, you cannot use env variables as keys in docker-compose (see [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/3108#issuecomment-248038373)). So there is no way to conditionally set either `image` or `build` options.

Comment: You're right, using multiple docker-compose files is the way to go. It looks like in order to avoid duplication between `docker-compose.dev.yml` and `docker-compose.prod.yml`, it's advisable keep any shared pieces in `docker-compose.yml` and create dev/prod specific versions of another file called `docker-compose.override.yml`. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends

Comment: Added another answer to expand on that a little bit. You definitely pointed me in the right direction here, thanks!