# Docker compose vs docker start

Tags: docker, jenkins, jhipster

I created a jhipster application with mysql.It is running.I can add,delete,list some records etc..MySql is running as docker container.With jenkins, I created another docker image which is called jhipster.Now, I can see my docker images with docker images command.I want to start my jhipster application as container but which commmand do I have to use?(docker-compose up -d or docker start containerID)

I have no docker-compose.yml file but I have app.yml file which is generated by jhipster.And app.yml refers mysql.yml file.Now,mysql container is running but there is no container about jhipster.Also, according to my dockerfile,jenkins should create  app.war but I cannot find that war in my remote ubuntu machine.From this point,which steps do I should follow? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The docker cli is used when managing individual containers on a docker engine. It is the client command line to access the docker daemon api.

The docker-compose cli can be used to manage a multi-container application. It also moves many of the options you would enter on the docker run cli into the docker-compose.yml file for easier reuse.

As you have only single container image `jhipster`, then you should use docker cli to run that image as container.

You can run following command:

```
docker images
```

It will give you the name of the image, then run:

```
docker run image_name:tag_name
```

If you don't provide any tag name it will run with `latest` tag

Comment: I have also mysql container which is already running.With jenkins, I created a jhipster image.Then , I run docker run containerId but console prints application is running but I have no access in my browser with http://IpAdressMachine:8080

Comment: It is working right now with this comamnd : docker run -p 8080:8080 -td imageId.The only problem is that I cannot use mysql container.My tables containes some record but I cannot see these records in UI

Comment: Please quote and link to sources of content you copy and paste: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37966689/596285

Comment: Could you please share your docker files of mysql and jenkins container?