# Does docker-compose configuration cover 100% of the docker CLI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to figure out the difference between `docker` and `docker-compose`, it looks like the `docker-compose` CLI effectively provides a means of running the `docker` CLI indirectly via configuration ([What is the difference between docker and docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966552/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-and-docker-compose)).

Is there anything that you can do with the `docker` CLI that COULDN'T be specified in `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker` CLI offers more options to you (e.g. `docker history` to inspect an image's history, just to name one) than the `docker-compose.yml`. But the latter is meant for a very different purpose, namely [making the deployment of multi-container applications easier](https://github.com/docker/compose).

So, to my knowledge, if we just look at the aspects of starting and configuring containers, you can do everything with `docker-compose` that "plain" `docker` can do, but in a much more comfortable way.

Comment: Thank you - it's interesting to know that the use of docker CLI comprises more than just managing a single container. But yes, I was asking the question specifically from the perspective of configuring / starting containers