# docker-compose is installed but docker compose is not recognized

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Running `docker compose up` gives `docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.`

But `docker-compose up` works just fine.

What gives? I thought compose was supposed to be part of the docker cli now.

How can I run `docker compose up` and get the same/similar behavior as `docker-compose up`?

`docker --version` -> `Docker version 20.10.10, build b485636f4b`

`docker-compose --version` -> `Docker Compose version 2.1.1`

Comment: Please follow the [Compose V2 installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#install-on-linux) or use `docker-compose` instead of `docker compose`.

Comment: I came across the problem which is on the opposite side:
After installing Docker v20 which includes compose, "docker compose" works, "docker-compose" doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because I had docker installed not through docker desktop.

I was using a minikube for my docker daemon, and the basic docker cli. But the basic cli (installed through `brew install docker`) doesn't have `docker compose`, that's part of docker desktop.

You can find the rest of that info here:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/

Answer (score -1):

Docker (in the cli is `docker`) and Docker Compose (on the cli is `docker-compose`) are different things.

Docker is the engine where the containers run

Docker-compose is a manager or orchestrator for those containers

This means that you cannot do `docker compose`, the correct command is `docker-compose`

I think you're confused on the commands

the way to start a container using `docker` (only 1 container) is

```
docker run -ti ubuntu bash
```

On the other hand you can do the same with Docker compose but you need a `docker-compose.yml` file where all the configuration is written, then to start it is

```
docker-compose up
```

**To sum up**

Docker and docker compose are 2 different things. You can find more info here [What is the difference between docker and docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966552/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-and-docker-compose)

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/
"The new Compose V2, which supports the compose command as part of the Docker CLI, is now available.
...

 You can test the Compose V2 by simply replacing the dash (-) with a space, and by running docker compose, instead of docker-compose."

Comment: @ForrestKeppler oh I didn't know that existed! per the docs did you do this step? https://github.com/docker/compose-switch/

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong but this switch is to translate 'docker-compose' statements into the new 'docker compose'

But I need 'docker compose' translated into 'docker-compose' because I dont have docker desktop installed.