# Difference between "docker compose" and "docker-compose"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

---

**Note**: this question was created BEFORE docker docs were updated (it was the reason they were updated - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66526176/1219280) answer). **Please do not post answers pointing out the docs on the differences** :-)

---

I have been using `docker-compose`, but noticed there is also a `docker compose` (without the dash).
I have not been able to quickly determine the differences between the two forms by googling.

Anyone?

`docker compose`'s help:

[image]

`docker-compose`'s help:

[image]

Comment: `docker compose` is the `compose` sub-command of the `docker` executable (which doesn't exist in this list https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/docker/). `docker-compose` is a separate executable: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: what do you mean by sub-command ? Was it not supposed to be listed [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/docker/) ?

Comment: I mean what is generally meant by a sub-command, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/637840

Comment: I don't think this should have been downvoted. It is a legitimate question, since it seems like "docker compose" is a valid command in the OPs terminal.

Comment: By the way, I am inclined to think JonrSharpe is correct. If so, however, I pushed a [git docker request](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/12454) to docker docs asking why is the `compose` sub command not listed in the child commands doc. Let's see what the response is.

Comment: By any chance, does someone have an idea how to force VS Code devcontainers to use "docker compose" and not "docker-compose" ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Brandon Mitchell](https://www.docker.com/captains/brandon-mitchell/) from [docker's Captain Program](https://www.docker.com/community/captains/) [replied](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/12454#issuecomment-792374011) to the [github issue I opened on this](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/12454#issue-823883873) as follows:

> The docker/compose-cli project is in an in-between state, where it's not available in upstream releases of the docker-cli Linux packages, but is being included in Docker Desktop. The documentation pages normally follow what's in the docker/cli, so having this released to Desktop early puts the documentation in a difficult position. I'm going to raise this issue with the Docker team to see how they'd like to handle it.

**Update:** from docker [github issue](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1404):

> gtardif commented 2 days ago
>
> compose command reference doc is now live

**new [docker compose command reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)**

Comment: Only yesterday did I realize BMitch and Brandon Mitchell are the same =]

Comment: Thanks for this! I've just installed the latest Docker Engine on a new machine and had a lot of commands running with `docker-compose`, which now fail. I found it useful to setup an alias for the new command: `alias docker-compose='docker compose'`.

Answer (score 318):

The `docker compose` (with a space) is a newer project to migrate compose to Go with the rest of the docker project. This is the `v2` branch of the [docker/compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/tree/v2) repo. It's been first introduced to Docker Desktop users, so docker users on Linux didn't see the command. In addition to migrating to Go, it uses the compose-spec, and part of the rewrite may result in behavior differences.

The original python project, called `docker-compose`, aka v1 of docker/compose repo, has now been deprecated and development has moved over to v2. To install the v2 `docker compose` as a CLI plugin on Linux, supported distribution can now install the `docker-compose-plugin` package. E.g. on debian, I run `apt-get install docker-compose-plugin`.

---

**Update**: since this question was asked, Linux installs have been updated by Docker to include compose v2 and docker-compose v1 is unlikely to receive any more updates.

Comment: use docker compose(newer version), instead of docker-compose(old version) https://docs.docker.com/compose/#compose-v2-and-the-new-docker-compose-command

Comment: On Arch Linux i just had to update

`sudo pacman -S docker`

Answer (score 8):

Quote from https://docs.docker.com/compose/#compose-v2-and-the-new-docker-compose-command

```
Compose V2 and the new docker compose command
    Important
    The new Compose V2, 
which supports the compose command as part of the Docker CLI, is now available.

    Compose V2 integrates compose functions into the Docker platform, 
continuing to support most of the previous docker-compose features and flags. 
You can run Compose V2 by replacing the hyphen (-) with a space, 
using docker compose, instead of docker-compose.
```

Comment: This was created following the github issue mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what has been already said here, I have noticed an important difference between the two.

In our setup, the `docker-compose.yml` file is located in a template folder. This way we can run multiple instances of the same project based on the same template. The local instance has its own folder with its own `.env` file (and also its own volumes).

There is also a template `.env` file in the template folder : copied and adapted to the instance folder using a script.

In order to work, the `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this, in the template folder :

```
version: "3"

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_wordpress"
    env_file:
      - ${PWD}/.env
 ...
```

And the local instance `.env` file :

```
# compose file location
COMPOSE_FILE=../templateFolder/docker-compose.yml

# this instance name
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=foo
```

In this context :

- with `docker-compose`, the `.env` file is read in the instance location, which is expected
- with `docker compose`, the `.env` file is read in the template location !

To override this, we had to rename the template `.env` file into `dotEnv`.

This behavior is very lightly described here : https://docs.docker.com/compose/features-uses/#have-multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host.

For posterity, the light description is:

> Compose uses a project name to isolate environments from each other. ...
>
> The default project name is the basename of the project directory. ...
>
> The default project directory is the base directory of the Compose file. A custom value for it can be defined with the --project-directory command line option.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. In the definition of your service `wordpress` you've defined `env_file` as a path defined with the aid of an environment variable. Does that variable PWD contain a relative or an absolute path?

Comment: An absolute one. `$PWD` provides the current path and is defined by your current sheel.

Comment: This isn't `pwd` but `PWD`. As far as I know it's not possible to call a shell function in a docker-compose.yml. The all-caps suggests it's an env var. -- EDIT: all right, I tried it and it worked. Learned sth new here. In that case, I can't imagine why the .env-File would be taken from different directories. Its value would be dependent on where the docker[-]compose was called, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

If it not yet included in the `docker` installation, `docker compose` can be installed on Linux as CLI plugin.

```
COMPOSE_VERSION=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | jq -r '.tag_name')

DOCKER_CONFIG=${DOCKER_CONFIG:-$HOME/.docker}
mkdir -p $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins
curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$COMPOSE_VERSION/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins/docker-compose
chmod +x $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#installing-compose-v2

Comment: Since March 2021, it comes installed in most distributions along with docker.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to have changes, but desire the original legacy `docker-compose` functionality, also known as Compose standalone vs. Compose plugin, you can do the following:

```bash
# Run as root
VERSION=v2.12.2
curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$VERSION/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# Test it
docker-compose
```

This allows you to e.g. keep using `docker-compose` in shell scripts.

[Check versions on this page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/other/).

Comment: For a smooth transition from v1 to v2 it is recommended to install this:
https://github.com/docker/compose-switch
works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Another notable difference between the two is how the docker image tags are generated. For both commands, the image tag is concatenation of COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME env var (project dir name if env var is not set) and `name` value from the compose file. For older `docker-compose` command the name is appended to COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME with an underscore, but the newer `docker compose` command appends the two with a hyphen/dash `-`

Consider the compose file:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: ./webapp
```

Assuming this compose file is present in the directory my_proj, the build command will generate different image tags.

`docker-compose build web` will generate `docker.io/library/my_proj_web`

`docker compose build web` will generate `docker.io/library/my_proj-web`

Comment: The network names is still generated with an underscore `_` while the hyphen `-` is used in the container names. (tested with docker 20.10.14 & docker-compose-plugin 2.3.3)

Answer (score 3):

There is more than just `docker-compoe` vs `docker compose`.

## The `docker-compose`

**Originally an external tool written in python.** Its goal was to handle multiple containers creation and link them together. https://github.com/docker/compose/tree/0.0.1
It used fig.yml config file at first.

At some point it became a part of docker desktop and was shipped with it.
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/previous-versions/archive-windows/

The config file was renamed from `fig.yml` to `compose.yml` at some point https://github.com/docker/compose/commit/2af7693e64010e11ba53f7fd923bb97f29b10063 and later to `docker-compose.yml` to better match binary name. It also supported `compose.override.yml` automatically loaded file and custom config files.

It took a lot of time but finally a new version rewritten in go lang replaced the old python version. It was called the docker-compose v2.

## The `docker compose` plugin

Docker-compose was **rewritten in go lang as a plugin for docker**, thus the command is no longer an external binary but a docker sub-command.

It went back to the `compose.yml` config file (and `compose.override.yml`).

## The config file versions

- Filename

  - `fig.yml` was expected. A warning was printed if `fig.yaml` was loaded instead.
  - `compose.yml` was the new config name
  - `docker-compose.yml` was introduced to better match binary name
  - `compose.yml` became again the preferred name as binary became a plugin of docker
- Content

  - New features were added and corresponding keywords - this long journey wouldn't be described here by me
  - The default network was changed at some point
  - The *docker swarm* project impacted syntax at some point - especially when looking at *deployment` and scaling
  - **File `/etc/hosts` was originally a shared file mounted to every container and updated when new containers were started** which allowed tools like `dnsmasq` to resolve container names https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1375/files
  - **In config version 2 the `/etc/hosts` was no longer updated breaking `dnsmasq` compatibility** but instead new barely documented `127.0.0.11` (that is eleven at the end) was added to the networking which is an internal dummy DNS resolver
  - Convig version 3 removed support for `extends` keywors along with a few others https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3 However current version supports config file extending https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/ and it is still supported https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#extends

    - I hope that this keyword would remain supported as it is a very valuable option for complex projects when you wish something like kubernetes but in a lighweight form

Originally
https://docs.docker.com/compose/

https://docs.docker.com/compose/history/