# What is the difference between `docker compose` and `docker-compose`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It seems that `docker compose *` mirrors many `docker-compose *` commands.

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "docker compose" and "docker-compose"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514436/difference-between-docker-compose-and-docker-compose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** `docker compose` is not considered a tech preview anymore. The rest of the answer still stands as-is, including the not-yet-implemented command.

`docker compose` is [currently a tech preview](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/), but is meant to be a drop-in replacement for `docker-compose`. It is being built into the `docker` binary to allow for new features. It [hasn't implemented one command yet, and has deprecated a few](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command-compatibility/). These are quite rarely used though, in my experience.

Answer (score 4):

The goal is that `docker compose` will eventually replace `docker-compose`, but no timeline for that yet and until that day you still need `docker-compose` for production.

Why they do that?
`docker-compose` is written in Python while most Docker developments are in Go. And they decided to recreate the project in Go with the same and more features, for better integration

Comment: Two very good answers. I have to choose one. A very hard decision ... This time I selected the other one for the additional reference.

Comment: Sounds like a rejection email from an employer haha. I'm glad to know the answer is useful to you @AxD