# Symfony 5 Cannot Find Docker Compose

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04, php-8.1

I'm trying to follow the [Symfony 5: The Fast Track](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/the-fast-track/en/1-tools.html) tutorial, and I'm stuck before I even leave the gate. I've made several attempts to uninstall and reinstall Docker, Docker Compose and Symfony CLI, but the command `symfony book:check-requirements` persistently returns the error message **Cannot find Docker Compose, please install it**, despite the fact that `docker --version` returns **Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086**, `docker compose version` returns **Docker Compose version v2.4.1**, and `docker run hello-world` runs successfully.

What am I doing wrong? What have I overlooked? I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 8.1, and am unfamiliar with either Docker or Symfony.

Comment: @Which Os are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  presume you are on Ubuntu. You should also install docker-compose
[how to install docker-compose on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Bear in bind that docker compose is not the same as docker-compose.They are separate executables. You can read more [difference between docker compose and docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514436/difference-between-docker-compose-and-docker-compose)

Comment: It seems the Fast Track tutorial needed docker-compose, not docker compose, although Digital Ocean's installation instructions didn't work for me - I had to install an older version using apt.