# Docker failed to fetch oauth token i/o timeout

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Trying to install retool locally on laptop. Thenen I ran into this issue while trying to use docker:

```
=> ERROR [retool-onpremise-db-connector internal] load metadata for docker.io/tryretool/backend:latest                                                                                                                                                                   20.7s
 => [auth] tryretool/backend:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
------
 > [retool-onpremise-db-connector internal] load metadata for docker.io/tryretool/backend:latest:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp: lookup auth.docker.io on 10.0.0.1:53: read udp 10.0.0.19:49993->10.0.0.1:53: i/o timeout
```

I have tried to `docker logout` and `docker login`, which doesn't help.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I tried setting buildkit(settings->Docker engine) as false and docker login, it worked once but for next time even those didn't help. I am using latest docker desktop version 4.15.0

Answer (score 0):

Try 'docker-compose build' instead of 'docker compose build'. docker-compose is the v1 branch of docker/compose repo , docker compose(without dash) is the v2 branch of docker/compose repo.

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514436/difference-between-docker-compose-and-docker-compose)

Comment: Where is the question using Compose? V2 should be used going forward anyway