# Error with deployment in shared server of angular with docker

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a problem with the deployment of my angular code with docker in a shared server.

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
# This file will use the Dockerfile to run a container with that image

version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    # build: . will make Docker Compose run 'docker image build .'
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480099/whats-the-difference-between-docker-compose-vs-dockerfile
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: test/angular
    
  #Nginx Service
  nginx-web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx-web
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - ./docker-configs/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./docker-configs/nginx/ssl/:/etc/ssl/

    # If we wanted more services, we'll put them right here
    #redis:
    #image: "redis:alpine"
#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

my Dockerfile

```
###############################################################################
# Stage 1: Compile and Build angular codebase
###############################################################################
# Use official node image as the base image
FROM node:16.0-alpine as node

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Add the source code to app
COPY . /app

# Install all the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Generate the build of the application
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server

# Use official nginx image as the base image
FROM nginx:latest


RUN apt update
RUN apt install vim libgpm2 vim-common vim-runtime xxd gpm vim-doc vim-scripts


# Copy the build output to replace the default nginx contents.
COPY --from=node /app/dist/web /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY /docker-configs/nginx/conf.d/nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
```

and this is my nginx-custom.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test-angular.eu;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/domain.tld.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.tld.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5; 
    
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

after i run docker-compose up, the page test-angular.eu is not accessible. But when i go to ip of my server, nginx is working.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you to everyone.

Comment: If the DNS name isn't resolvable but the IP address works then that sounds like a DNS problem, and not anything related to the setup you've shown here.  When you say "it's not accessible", what happens?  The Dockerfile you've shown isn't obviously used in this setup (it's built and a container is started from its image, but it does not have `ports:` and it's not on the same network as a separate Nginx proxy), is it required to demonstrate the issue?  How does your image use vim to serve requests; can you delete the two `apt` lines?