# Confusion between Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am just trying to dockerize my Spring Boot app with MySQL database and at the beginning I see that I can do that by running some necessary commands as shown below:

```
docker pull mysql:8.0
```

```
docker network create springmysql-net
```

```
docker run --name mysqldb --network springmysql-net -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e 
MYSQL_DATABASE=employee-db -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=****** -d mysql:8.0
```

```
// update application properties:
url: jdbc:mysql://<container-name>:3306/employee-db&useSSL=false
```

```
docker build -t backend .
```

```
docker run --network springmysql-net --name backend-container -p 8080:8080 -d backend
```

And the `Dockerfile` is as shown below:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/employee-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar employee-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "employee-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Here is the points that I could not be sure or understand:

**1.** Assume that we send the jar file to the customer and want them to run the app on Docker with less effort. I think we can make all of those commands to be executed automatically. But I am not sure for which file should we use for this. Do we need `Dockerfile`? Or `docker-compose.yml`?

**2.** I also use `docker-compose.yml` to create container and making necessary settings for development. But, I am not sure what is the purpose of `Dockerfile`? It seems tı be also used for automation of this procedures.  Any clarification pls?

**3.** In most of the examples, `FROM openjdk:8` is used. I think it is related to that there is no JRE of Java 11. So, can it be also used as `FROM openjdk:8` on Dockerfile for Java 11 or Java 17 applications?

Comment: When you want to deploy your application via docker, you should ideally deliver a built docker image. The docker compose file could be used to setup the application stack. Maybe you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480099/whats-the-difference-between-docker-compose-vs-dockerfile).

Comment: Do you mean that it is only used for application related tasks e.g. copying jar files from target folder, etc.? But I also remember it is used for installing images, and some other commands. Any clarification pls?

Comment: And what do you think about my other questions?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Assume that we send the jar file to the customer and want them to run the app on Docker with less effort. I think we can make all of
>    those commands to be executed automatically. But I am not sure for
>    which file should we use for this. Do we need Dockerfile? Or
>    docker-compose.yml?

You could send the customer a `Dockerfile` with commands to `build` and `run` the Docker container, or you could send them a `docker-compose.yml` file and the customer would likely only need to run `docker-compose up`. If the customer will be using the `docker-compose.yml` file though, you'll also need to provide the image built from the `Dockerfile` or the `Dockerfile` itself with relevant context needed to build it. Giving the customer any files related to application code or more sensitive variables should be decided in a conversation with the customer.

> 2. I also use docker-compose.yml to create container and making necessary settings for development. But, I am not sure what is the
>    purpose of Dockerfile? It seems tı be also used for automation of this
>    procedures. Any clarification pls?

The Dockerfile basically contains the instructions to build the Docker image so that the image is built the same way on any machine.

> 3. In most of the examples, FROM openjdk:8 is used. I think it is related to that there is no JRE of Java 11. So, can it be also used as
>    FROM openjdk:8 on Dockerfile for Java 11 or Java 17 applications?

You should take note that that image has been deprecated and will no longer be maintained, so you should check out a different base image to use from the variants listed on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk). For example, you can use an [amazoncorreto base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/amazoncorretto) that starts with whatever Java version you're targeting.

Comment: Wonderful explanations. Regarding to your answers >>>

Comment: **1.** Which files should I provide to the customer? Are `*jar`, `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` enough? Or should I also provide `application.yml` as well? Because if I do not include the connection properties in `docker-compose.yml`, the customer will probably need to `application.yml`. Could you explain a little bit more pls?

Comment: **2.** You can also share an example Dockerfile, it would be so useful for me.

Comment: **3.** Hmmm, very important point, then I should use `FROM amazoncorretto:11` in my Dockerfile for Java 11.

Comment: Related to 1, I've updated the answer slightly. Don't give away any application code or secrets unless you and the customer understand how sensitive they are. Regarding 2, you included a Dockerfile above which is a good place to start. I wouldn't be able to generate a Dockerfile for you unless I knew everything about your application. Seeing as your original questions were answered, please upvote and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for reply, already upvoted for your helps. On the other hand, sending docker-compose.yml without Dockerdile seems better option as it seems much easier to run the app. However, I could not understand the function of Dockerfile. When I look at it, it copies jar file to a location (probably the location in the container of the app). So, if I don't provide it, how the docker-compose proceed without it? Also I think I need to provide jar file that you did not mentioned, right?